# error creating Batch Compute Environment (<name>) Error executing request, Exception : arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/xyz role is not authorised

Tags: amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, aws-batch, aws-iam-policy

I'm creating an AWS IAM role with the following terraform block. This enables `AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy` permission.

```hcl
resource "aws_iam_role" "my_ecs_task_execution_role" {
  name_prefix = "my_ecs_task_execution_role"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
  description = "Allows ECS tasks to call AWS ECS on your behalf."
}
```

And I'm using the above IAM role to create a AWS Batch Job Definition like below.

```hcl
resource "aws_batch_job_definition" "job_def_m_8_c_4" {
  name = "m_8_c_4"
  type = "container"
  platform_capabilities = ["EC2"]
  container_properties = <<CONTAINER_PROPERTIES
  {
    "executionRoleArn": "${aws_iam_role.my_ecs_task_execution_role.arn}",
    "image": "<image_uri>",
    "memory": 8000,
    "vcpus": 4 
  }
CONTAINER_PROPERTIES
  timeout {
    attempt_duration_seconds = 21600
  }
}
```

And I've also added the necessary job queue and the compute environment.

But the problem here, when I run `terraform apply`, I'm getting some strange errors for the first time that -

```
 error creating Batch Job Definition (m_8_c_4): : Error executing request, Exception : 
arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/my_ecs_task_execution_rolexyz role is not authorized., 
RequestId: xyzzys-xyzxyz-xyzxyxz
```

> And I using Terraform - v1.4.4

**Solutions that I already tried**

I tried adding `"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:root"` to `aws_iam_role.my_ecs_task_execution_role` and again got the same result.

I've also verified the STS endpoints and they are active across all regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your role does not appear to have any permissions. Defining the `assume_role_policy` will merely allow ECS to assume the role.

Consider attaching the `AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy` AWS-managed policy to your role:

```hcl
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_task_execution_role_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.my_ecs_task_execution_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}
```